# Delete function does not run in ExtJS 5.1.1

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, controller

I have defined a Delete function which will delete the record on Gridpanel but somehow it does not do anything! During debugging it comes `rec.destroy` section and then skip whole the code block; with no error, no XHR request, just nothing.

I have wondered maybe that's happening because of `rec` variable not loading but quite the contrary it's getting required data inside.

Why is that could be happening?

```
doDeleteEmployee: function () {
var me = this;
var rec = me.getEmployeeForm().getRecord();
Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm Delete User', 'Are you sure you want to delete user ' + rec.get('firstName') + '?', function (btn) {
    if (btn === 'yes') {
        rec.erase({
                success: function(rec, operation) {
                    console.log('success step one');
                    me.getStore().load();
                    console.log('success step two');
                    Ext.MessageBox.alert('INFO', 'Delete Success');
                },
                failure: function(rec, operation) {
                    console.log('this is failure');
                    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Delete Failure', operation.request.scope.reader.jsonData.msg);
                }
        });
    }
});
```

}

**EDIT** (just after suggestion of @scebotari66):

Still getting error after define **erase** method. *(I've update the the 'doDeleteEmployee' function above)*

I got idea for `erase` but this the result after debugging process: 
1. During debugging, it comes to `rec.erase` and skip the rest block which inside. When i tried go step by step, i've noticed; it keeps correct data till `afterDrop()` function of **ext-debug**.js.
2. I have defined two console.log -as you will notice above- and it displays only the *'success step one'*.
3. In Network tab of Dev-Tool's, there is **XHR** request but somehow it sends with HTTP: **POST** method and gets 200-OK as response. So i thought, maybe I am doing something wrong with Model and added below.

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('Employee.model.EmployeeMdl', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['Ext.data.identifier.Sequential'],
    identifier: {
        type: 'sequential',
        seed: 1223334477,
        increment: 10
    },
    fields: [
        {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'lastName', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'email', type: 'string'}
    ],
    idProperty: 'id',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'      
        },
        api: {
            read: 'http://...0.223:8223/orest/employee',
            create: 'http://...0.223:8223/orest/employee',
            update: 'http://...0.223:8223/orest/employee',
            destroy: 'http://...0.223:8223/orest/employee'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            allowSingle: true,
            encode: false,
            writeAllFields: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to destroy the record via the proxy, you should use the [erase](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.Model.html#method-erase) method.

The [destroy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.Base.html#method-destroy) method is inherited by Ext.data.Model from Ext.Base, and it's not usually directly invoked when dealing with models.

> This method is called to cleanup an object and its resources. After
>   calling this method, the object should not be used any further.

**Updated**

1. It skips the rest of the code because you are getting the error.
2. If you return a successful response, the `success` callback will be called.
3. It is normal that it sends a `POST` request. This is how the ajax proxy works. If you want to customize this, you need to take a look at the [actionMethods](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax.html#cfg-actionMethods) config.

> Mapping of action name to HTTP request method. In the basic AjaxProxy
>   these are set to 'GET' for 'read' actions and 'POST' for 'create',
>   'update' and 'destroy' actions.

Comment: Dear @scebotari66 thanks for your reply. I had update some information on code snippet. Hope to you will have time check it.

Comment: How do you create the record. You load it individually, or it is created when you load a store?

Comment: I am trying to delete created records on DB. So records creates when i load the store.

Comment: Dear @scebotari66, I've add `me.getEmployeeList()` just before `getStore().load();` of **success** method. Now it displays both console.log, Ext.MessageBox and of course refresh the grid with this editing. Also XHR is 200-OK but still record stays on the DB? :-/

Comment: This already seems to be a server side issue. It should return the result only after the record has been remove from the DB. Does the record still exist when you later reload the store?

Comment: No it doesn't exist on the Grid but still exist on server. As well server configured as to displaying random 200 records and this situation happens after Updating a record as well. So probably that's why i can not see.

Comment: Dear @scebotari66, I have followed the server call stack and figure out that the problem come up due to Server! As well i understand that this Delete method works well and triggers the server (at least gives the error). Thanks for your time.